# Wordpress: Parameter for Shortcode function

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to create a shortcode in Wordpress, in which the function that is called with the shortcode tag gets the shortcode tag as parameter.

So say I have

```
<?php
var $shortcode = 'my_shortcode_tag';
add_shortcode( $shortcode, 'my_shortcode_function');
?>
```

then I want `'my_shortcode_function'` to know the shortcode tag by it was called. I know that I could use attributes as in `[my_shortcode_tag tag='my_shortcode_tag']` when I call the shortcode in my actual post, but I want to be able to just write `[my_shortcode_tag]` and my function to know that it was called by that tag. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is sent in as the third argument to a shortcode function (as mentioned in the [Shortcodes API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes)).

for example:

```
add_shortcode( 'shortcode1', 'my_shortcode_function');
add_shortcode( 'shortcode2', 'my_shortcode_function');

function my_shortcode_function($atts, $content, $sc) {
    return $sc;
}
```

this will output the name of the shortcode called for that function.